# Discrete Topology unit disk/unit ball

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $Y$= {$a,b$} be equipped with the discrete Topology. Show that the unit disk

$\mathbb{D}$= {$y\in Y$ | $d(y,a) \le 1$} is *not* the closure of the open unit ball

$B_1 (a)$ = {$y\in Y$ | $d(y,a) < 1$}.

I understand how to word out the interior and closure generally, but I don't even know where to start with this case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B_1(a)=\{a\}$ which has itself as a closure while $\mathbb{D} = Y$ which is not equal to $\{a\}$.